# Using jQuery in a wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, wordpress-theming

I want to use a jquery plugin in a wordpress theme but am having trouble getting it to work.

In functions.php I have:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?> 
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquerycountdownpackjs', '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/jquery.countdown.pack.js', array('jquery'),'1.2.6'); ?>
```

Is this all I need to tell wordpress to load jQuery and then load my plugin?

In header.php I begin the jquery with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

What else am I missing? 
The div which should display the result of the plugin is not displaying anything. Am I loading jQuery correctly?

Comment: @mrtsherman the version number you're referencing in your comment is for the countdownpack plugin the OP is using, not jquery.

Comment: What is the actual problem mate? Can we have a test link for your website? Are there any JS errors on your console?

Comment: Is this not the correct way to load Wordpress's version of jQuery: <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>  Do I need to do any thing to load it?
The problem is that the div which should display the plugin is not displaying anything on the page.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just jQuery, you are after, you need to put in your header.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

**Note**: This function will not work if it is called from a wp_head or wp_print_scripts actions, as the files need to be enqueued before those actions are run.

The actual jQuery script needs to be in either document.ready wrapper or in self invoking anonymous function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

or the SIAF

```
(function($) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If you want to enqueue another script for the countdown plugin, just add a line:
`code`<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquerycountdownpackjs', get_template_directory_uri() .'/jquery.countdown.pack.js', array('jquery')); ?>`code`